# OAuthException in Twitter with Flask, using OAuthlib.client

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, flask

I'm trying just to redirect a person if he/she logs int with Twitter.
So, in views I have:

```
    @twitter.tokengetter
    def get_twitter_token():
      if 'twitter_oauth' in flask.session:
      resp = flask.session['twitter_oauth']
    return resp['oauth_token'], resp['oauth_token_secret']


    @app.before_request
    def before_request():
      flask.g.user = None
      if 'twitter_oauth' in flask.session:
      flask.g.user = flask.session['twitter_oauth']

    @app.route('/login')
    def login():
      callback_url = flask.url_for('oauthorized', next=flask.request.args.get('next'))
    return twitter.authorize(callback=callback_url or flask.request.referrer or None)

    @app.route('/logout')
    def logout():
      flask.session.pop('twitter_oauth', None)
      return redirect(flask.url_for('index'))

    @app.route('/oauthorized')
    def oauthorized():
      resp = twitter.authorized_response()
      if resp is None:
        flask.flash('You denied the reques to sign in')
      else:
        flask.session['twitter_oauth'] = resp
      return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('success'))
```

I've already configured de TW_APP_ID and TW_APP_SECRET values in my configs.py, and when I execute, it just raises me a

```
       flask_oauthlib.client.OAuthException
       OAuthException: Failed to generate request token
```

Why is this for? What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry if there's a bad identation error. I checked in my code and everything is alright.

Answer (score 0):

The Flask-OAuthlib examples were broken. They were fixed in https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/issues/90 .

You must handle the case `isinstance(resp, OAuthException)`.

Check this commit to understand the changes made to the examples: https://github.com/PyBossa/pybossa/commit/26ec807e321da2f87e1ab44149f5b40ae04bf8bd

Comment: The relevant issue on GitLab: https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/issues/191